# How to change font and color of sections in memoir?

Tags: latex, memoir

I have a test document using `memoir` and I'd like to figure out how to change the font and color of sections and lower levels.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Helvetica}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I understand that `memoir` includes the functionality of `titlesec`, and this seems to be described in section 6 of the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en), but I just can't figure out the incantation to make it work. If I wanted `\section` to be in the sans font in blue, and the lower levels to be in green, what are the commands to make this happen?

Answer (score 7):

Use `\setXheadstyle{<style>}` to set the `<style>` of `X` where

- `sec` denotes `\section`,
- `subsec` denotes `\subsection`
- `subsubsec` denotes `\subsubsection`,
- `para` denotes `\paragraph`, and
- `subpara` denotes `\subparagraph`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext,xcolor}

\setsecheadstyle{\sffamily\color{blue}}% Set \section style
\setsubsecheadstyle{\sffamily\color{green}}% Set \subsection style

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```